# What is the name of the test I had on my first day at gym?

Tags: gym, metabolism

I had been diagnosed diabetic recently and hence decided to go to gym for the first time.

The gentleman there gave me a test that I suppose is checking my fitness or metabolism and it was basically done by putting me no the cycling machine, keep raising the resistance while taking the readings of my heart rate at the end of each 5 min on the specific resistance level, then move to the higher resistance.
I guess this test indicated to him that I haven't been exercising and I am not in a good shape and he chose some introductory plan for me to start with.

My question is what is this test called and what is it exactly testing?

Can I do it to myself?

Is getting better scores on this test means my body is burning sugars better which means better position with my diabetes?

[EDIT] Just wanted to add that the final equation was using my weight, age, and the heart rate against each resistance level to get a final number.

Comment: Most likely they conducted a stress test on you.

Comment: oh ok, can you please elaborate on what is a stress test and what is it exactly measuring? thanks

Comment: Google is your friend. It is widely used to check for cardio vascular conditioning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a former [ACE](https://www.acefitness.org/default.aspx?adpos=1t1&creative=197105854746&device=c&matchtype=b&network=g&gclid=CJC2k5zYttUCFQtLDQodvYsN6w) certified trainer.  What you describe sounds very much like the [YMCA Sub-maximal Bicycle Test](http://www.exrx.net/Testing/YMCACycleTest.html).  It's used to evaluate physical work capacity, especially for someone new to the gym.  It's used to estimate maximal oxygen uptake.  It's a way to establish a relationship between heart rate and workload.  Trainers typically perform this test on someone new to determine a base line for exercise planning.  This test has nothing to do with metabolism.

Comment: Could this indicate in any way my progress with type 2 diabetes? isn't oxygen consumption used as well to measure metabolism? I guess there might still be some connection

Comment: The test is only meant to obtain a baseline for planning your fitness routine(s).  A certified personal trainer will not test for any medical/health issues.  That's not their area of expertise.